# xcode11 how to give a selected option an action, in a PickerView. So that when I select an option in the selected array, I can perform an action to it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uipickerview

For example I select in the PickerView ( country: Scotland, City: Aberdeen ) once I have selected both options in a picker view, I would select a button and have that action take me to another page with information about Scotland, Aberdeen specifically.

What I am trying to do is have my PickerView options take me to another page contained with data specific with those options selected. This is what I have coded so far.

```
import UIKit

class GrapplingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var trainingTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var areaTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var focusTextField: UITextField!
    
            
   
    
    let training = ["Skill Reciting", "Sparring"]
            let area = ["Takedowns", "Top Battle", "Bottom Battle", "Survival"]
            let focus = ["Full Training", "Specific Training"]
    
           
            
            var trainingPickerView = UIPickerView ()
            var areaPickerView = UIPickerView ()
            var focusPickerView = UIPickerView()
            
            
            
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          

          title = "Grappling"
      
                
                
                trainingTextField.inputView = trainingPickerView
                areaTextField.inputView = areaPickerView
                focusTextField.inputView = focusPickerView
                
                
    
                trainingTextField.placeholder = "Select training type"
                areaTextField.placeholder = "Select start position"
                focusTextField.placeholder = "Select your focus"
    
                
                
                trainingTextField.textAlignment = .center
                areaTextField.textAlignment = .center
                focusTextField.textAlignment = .center
    
              
                
    
                trainingPickerView.delegate = self
                trainingPickerView.dataSource = self
            areaPickerView.delegate = self
            areaPickerView.dataSource = self
                focusPickerView.delegate = self
            focusPickerView.dataSource = self
                
                
                
                trainingPickerView.tag = 1
                areaPickerView.tag = 2
                focusPickerView.tag = 3
          
               
    }
            }
            
        

        extension GrapplingViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
            
            func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }
            
            func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
                switch pickerView.tag {
                case 1:
                    return training.count
                    case 2:
                        return area.count
                case 3:
                    return focus.count
                default:
                    return 1
                }
            }
            
           
            
            func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
                switch pickerView.tag {
                case 1:
                    return training[row]
                case 2:
                        return area[row]
                case 3:
                    return focus[row]
                default:
                    return "Data not found"
            }
            }
            
            
            
            func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
                
                switch pickerView.tag {
                    case 1:
                        trainingTextField.text = training[row]
                        trainingTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                    case 2:
                           areaTextField.text = area[row]
                            areaTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                    case 3:
                        focusTextField.text = focus[row]
                        focusTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                    default:
                        return
                }
            }
    

         @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
              
               

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to go the next view controller only after all three options are selected in the picker view you can try this.

Each time your `didSelectRow` method, save the option that was selected. For eg: I would have three properties, one each for `selectedTraining`, `selectedArea` and `selectedFocus`.

Each time the `didSelectRow` is called, in the case statement, check if the other two variables have a value. If yes, then, assuming the `GrapplingViewController` is hooked up to another viewContoller, you can calll `performSegue` method.